# How to convert an array of integer to an octal number?

Tags: c, decimal, octal

I have an array like this:
int arr[8] = {6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 6}.
How to convert this array to an octal number 64161156.
I use this code but its result is 364602604, 364602604 is decimal number 64161156 represented as octal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[8] = {6, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 6};
    int octal = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        octal = octal * 10 + a[i];

    printf("%o\n", octal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Multiply by 8 instead of 10.

Comment: An "octal number" is a string. Computers typically store integers in a binary format. What you are doing makes no sense no matter what you are multiplying by, unless you are trying to convert *from* octal.

Comment: @AndréCaldas yes, that was my point. The conversion is **from** octal, not **to** octal as asked. It's an array of octal digits being converted to binary format. And I haven't downvoted, voted to close, or attempted to "disqualify" nicky.

Comment: @AndréCaldas It's a common beginner misconception that we actually need to write programs converting between various bases when it's in fact all binary. The base only matters when we display something to a human user/programmer. Therefore programmers mostly use decimal and hex because those are convenient formats to the programmer - it all boils down to raw binary anyway. As for displaying numbers to users - when we do so we often need to convert raw data into a string.

Comment: @Lundin: yes. But the problem is very well posed: I have an array of eight digits 0-7. I want to construct an `int octal` that contains the corresponding number if the original array is interpreted as the digits of an octal number. So there is no "what you are doing makes no sense". Possibly nicky doesn't even have enough maturity even to understand what does not make sense in Weather Vane's opinion. I don't think this kind of treatment is fair to the OP, who got -2 for a question that is that bad. But I do understand you both. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A good idea is to organize the mathematical part before jump into programing.

The idea of what you want to do is:

> result = a[7] + 8*a[6] + 8*8*a[5] + ... + 8*8*8*8*8*8*8*a[0].

(sorry, I could not figure out how to write mathematics here at SO)

What your code does is:

> result = a[7] + 10*a[6] + 10*10*a[5] + ... + 10*10*10*10*10*10*10*a[0].

As [@Weather Vane pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469617/how-to-convert-an-array-of-integer-to-an-octal-number#comment136574626_77469617), internally the `int octal` is just a number. When you print it, it is print in whatever system you instruct the "print method" to do. So, your code is calculating in decimal and printing in octal.

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow does not support MathJax formatting.